# How to create new user document in firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am trying to implement this logic, when user successfully registers, app creates a document with `id=user.email` in firestore. For that, I created following security rule in firestore:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read: if request.auth != null;
    }
    match /users/{userId}{
        allow read: if request.auth != null;
        allow write: if request.auth.token.email == userId;
    }
  }
}
```

and following code in my app:

```
const { email, password, name, lastName } = value;

firebase
  .auth()
  .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  .then(() => {
        firestore.collection('users').doc(email).set({
          name, lastName
        })
        .then(function(docRef) {
          console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
        });
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Main')
      })
  .catch(error => alert(error))
```

when I run my app, I am getting following error:

```
Error adding document: , [FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.]
```

Comment: Did you solve the problem?
I have the similar rule `allow write: if request.auth.token.email == userId;` and as a result I have the same error.

Answer (score 8):

It's not a good idea to use the email address of the user as a unique identifier, as that can change over time.  It's better to use the unique user id (uid) assigned by Firebase Authentication.

Rules:

```
match /users/{userId} {
    allow read: if request.auth != null;
    allow write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
}
```

Code:

```
firebase
  .auth()
  .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  .then(userCredential => {
        firestore.collection('users').doc(userCredential.user.uid).set({
          name, lastName
        })
```

This is far more common, makes it easier to write security rules, and is resistant to email changes.